# How to inject decorator parameters into docstring?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-decorators, docstring

I am using a specific decorator pattern in my API which looks something like this (simplified):

```
@api(
    path='/double',
    method='GET',
    input={'x': int},
    output={'x_double': int}
)
def double(x):
    """
    This endpoint doubles the number you give it.

    Args:
        x: (int) the number you want to double

    Returns:
        x_double: (int) x * 2

    """
    return jsonify({'x_double': x*2})
```

I am using **Sphinx** to generate my docs. I want to inject the decorator's parameters into the docstring of the function that it decorates. For the above example I would expect the documentation to look like this:

```
    mypackage.something module

    mypackage.something.double(x)

    This endpoint doubles the number you give it.

    Attributes:
        path: /double
        method: GET

    Args:
        x: (int) the number you want to double

    Returns:
        x_double: (int) x * 2
```

How can I achieve this? I was thinking of writing a script that injects these into the generated docs, but was wondering if there is perhaps an easier way?

Also, yes, the decorator is using `functools.wraps`.

Comment: The tricky part here would be inserting the attributes between the description and the args. But can't the decorator generate the `Args` and` `Returns` section from the `input` and `output` parameters? Then you could simply append the generated string to `double.__doc__`, which would just contain `"This endpoint doubles the number you give it"`.

Comment: (I'm assuming you wrote `api()`; if not, you could write your *own* decorator that calls `api()`.)

Comment: @chepner yes I wrote `api()`

Comment: @chepner  I see what you're referring to, that should work!